# Exporting to CSV (using built in tools) - incorrect characters

Tags: freemarker, moqui

When I export data from a screen using built-in `show-csv-button="true"`, the application prints incorrect characters on places of special characters (the EUR sign, accent marks). Can I fix it by changing character set?

Comment: Using export to text works well, all characters are correct.

Comment: This seems like more of an issue than a question. For issue reporting it is helpful to describe your complete process so that others can reproduce it, or at least understand what you're trying to do. For example, the complete process (including how you are producing and looking at the generated file), what you expected to see, and how what you are seeing is different.

Comment: Shall I submit it to github as an issue with more details?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue of managing the way MS Excel loads CSV. Opening it directly from browser downloads causes the problem. When I import the file in a standard way, letting Excel check the character set, data is OK.

Using Excel's import utility, it recognizes the UTF-8.

[image]

When opening from OS, 1250: Central European is used.

[image]